# How to install git subrepo in Git for Windows running bash shell

Tags: git, git-for-windows, git-subrepo

I know there are instructions to install [gitsubrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) in Git for windows [here](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo).

I understand what I have to do, however, I do not know where to find the shell startup script. I have installed the Git Bash shell, and I am at a loss for where its shell startup script is located.

Does anyone know where the startup script is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as:

- `git` is in your `$PATH`
- [git subrepo `.rc` file](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo/blob/2f6859642ae9104a9699021218bf607598f5a0ea/.rc) has been added to your `.bashrc` (`source /path/to/git-subrepo/.rc' >> ~/.bashrc`, done from a git bash session)

You can use a regular git-bash shell, and start typing `git subrepo` commands.

The "shell startup configuration" is the `.rc` file which is where you have cloned the repository (in `/c/path/to/your/git-subrepo/clone` within a git bash session)

If you clone in C:\Users\Me\git-subrepo, you would need to type in a bash session:

```
source /c/Users/Me/git-subrepo/.rc' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The [OP wiyosaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525496/wiyosaya) did (in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877540/how-to-install-git-subrepo-in-git-for-windows-running-bash-shell/71880091#comment127074371_71880091)):

- create the .bashrc: `touch ~/.bashrc`
- add the missing line: `echo source /c/GitHub/git-subrepo/.rc >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure out, with the help of your answer, how to get the requisite line into the .bashrc file, and I can type in git subrepo from a bash command prompt - without any options - and it gives me the help output. I seem to be all set.

Comment: @wiyosaya Great, well done! What line did you need?

Comment: First off, the .bashrc file was not there. So, in a bash command prompt, I typed "source /c/GitHub/git-subrepo/.rc'  >> ~/.bashrc"
For whatever reason, the line was not added to the .bashrc file, but it did create an empty .bashrc file. I then found that file, and added the line "source /c/GitHub/git-subrepo/.rc" to the file, and that was all I needed.

Thanks again!

Comment: @wiyosaya OK, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as the relevant commands.

Comment: sounds good, however, it might be easier to understand, IMO, if the added line were just source /c/GitHub/git-subrepo/.rc - I knew enough to figure it out, and the "touch" line makes sense. I also have a great windows search program Everything - https://www.voidtools.com/ where the .bashrc file appeared after I tried the command without the echo statement.

Comment: @wiyosaya Nice, I didn't know about "everything". No way to use it at work through: it needs admin privileges to index NTFS volumes.